# Use meshgrid with two different vectors

Tags: matlab

I want to create a grid what is saved in a matrix (nx3) (here: obsPos) with zeros in the third column. The grid should be uniformly spaced. The matrix should be defined by two vectors (dim: 3x1).

Objective: To create a mesh what is x meters long and y meters wide and save positions of this mesh into a matrix. This mesh should be evenly distributed, e. g. each mesh panel is one square meters big.

Cheers!

```
obsXlimit = 50; % Define size of the observer grid in x-direction (m)
obsYlimit = 20; % Define size of the observer grid in y-direction (m)

obsXspanVector = [obsXlimit 0];
obsYspanVector = [0 obsYlimit];

[obsX obsY] = meshgrid(obsXspanVector,obsYspanVector); % Generate X and Y data of the observer positions

obsZ = zeros(size(obsX, 1)); % Generate Z data of the observer positions (always with obsZ = 0)

obsPos = [obsX(:), obsY(:), obsZ(:)]; % Save every observer position
```

Comment: I do not really understand the question. Could you give an example? Alternatively, what should the given code return?

Comment: I've edited my question. Does this help?

Comment: Well, if my answer answers your question, then yes :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You state uniform grid, this is obtained using `start:step:stop` with `start`, `step` and `stop` being the point where the grid starts, the stepsize and where it ends respectively. As it seems, you have the grids as

```
obsXspanVector = [obsXlimit 0];
obsYspanVector = [0 obsYlimit];
```

Wich will make a grid only consisting of the start and endpoint. Additionally, as one square has to be 1 square meter big, I presume the stepsize should be one:

```
obsXspanVector = 0:1:obsXlimit;
obsYspanVector = 0:1:obsYlimit;
```

Then you can generate the grid for x and y with

```
[obsX obsY] = meshgrid(obsXspanVector,obsYspanVector);
```

Then to avoid forgetting, redefine the arrays `obsX` and `obsY` to be their Nx1 equivalent.

```
obsX = obsX(:);
obsY = obsY(:);
```

Then you can draw the zeros needed, though noticing that `zeros` with 1 input makes a square matrix, and multiple inputs (possibly as array) give an array of the specified size

```
obsZ = zeros(size(obsX)); %size(obsX) = [N, 1]
```

and finally, you can merge

```
obsPos = [obsX(:), obsY(:), obsZ(:)];
```

Comment: This is awesome!! But I can't plot the surface with `surf (obsX, obsY, obsZ); % Plot the observer plane`

Comment: I've solved it using `obsZplot = zeros(size(obsX,1)); % Create zero matrix´ for plotting for plotting`

Comment: If I answered your question, please consider to accept the answer. [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).